# Avoid overwriting the file just created

Tags: excel, vba

The code creates folders and saves an Excel file according to today's date as soon as you open the template. Once you modify the template, you can just hit the save button and print it out.

The problem arises when you open the template for the second time in the same day, it will overwrite the existing file. Is there a way to check if a file exists (according to today's date)? If so, show a message saying it already exists, and if not, to follow the code as is?

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents MonitorApp As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim strGenericFilePath      As String: strGenericFilePath = "\\Server2016\Common\Register\"
Dim strYear                 As String: strYear = Year(Date) & "\"
Dim strMonth                As String: strMonth = MonthName(Month(Date)) & "\"
Dim strDay                  As String: strDay = Day(Date) & "\"
Dim strFileName             As String: strFileName = "Register Sheet " & Format(Date, "mmm dd yyyy")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
' Check for year folder and create if needed
If Len(Dir(strGenericFilePath & strYear, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir strGenericFilePath & strYear
End If
' Check for month folder and create if needed
If Len(Dir(strGenericFilePath & strYear & strMonth, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir strGenericFilePath & strYear & strMonth
End If
' Check for date folder and create if needed
If Len(Dir(strGenericFilePath & strYear & strMonth & strDay, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir strGenericFilePath & strYear & strMonth & strDay
End If
' Save File
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
strGenericFilePath & strYear & strMonth & strDay & strFileName, _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
' Popup Message
MsgBox "File Saved As: " & vbNewLine & strGenericFilePath & strYear & strMonth & strDay & strFileName
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you already have the answer yourself. The Dir-function works for both folders and files.

So you can check if the file exists in the same way you check if the folders exist.

```
If len(dir(strGenericFilePath & strYear & strMonth & strDay & strFileName & ".xlsm")) = 0 then

    'save file..
Else

    msgbox("File already exists")

End if
```

should do the trick

Comment: Im unsure as the where to insert the remaining code. I did not write the original code, and i'm not that savvy on VBA. Would i insert that after the day folder is created or should i be replacing a line?

Comment: I figured it out. I ended up inserting this code right after the day folder creation code. Thank you Beek.

Comment: Glad to see you got to the solution you needed. Since the code doesn't really do anything if the file exists (if the file exists, the folders exist so nothing happens), it doesn't matter too much where you insert it. Starting off with it makes the most sense, because if the file exist, all your other code becomes irrelevant to run through.